# Facebook login in facebook's app internal browser not working

Tags: android, ios, facebook, mobile, facebook-login

I have a landing page with Facebook login in this url:
http://moda.ropeo.co/aconseja1a

It works as expected, but when I click in one of my Facebook ads from mobile (Android and IOS) that takes the user to the landing, the landing is rendered in the "App's internal browser".

For some reason this internal browser is not rendering the "Login with Facebook" button! What is going on? how can I fix it?

thank you.

EDIT

html button code:

```
<div class="fb-login-button" data-max-rows="1" data-size="large" data-width="260" data-button-type="login_with" data-show-faces="false" data-use-continue-as="true" data-scope="email" onlogin="checkLoginState(),console.log('connected')"></div>
```

Comment: Android code required. None given. That's an integral part of any question.

Comment: it's not on Android.. it's web! I will edit though. It's just not working from Facebook's Android and IOS App..

Comment: how you handle the login process ? do you used something special?

Comment: @Alejandro If it's not Android why is it tagged Android?

Comment: Because error happens in Facebook for Android

Comment: @Ibrahim nope just the simple example from their documentation. I will test further on this though

Comment: @Alejandro i think your code will work if the device doesn't have facebook app.

Comment: Any resolve here? I'm having the same issue :(

Comment: I solved it by creating my own button and handle it through js.